# como puedo resolver este problema?

Tags: python

Cree un script que le solicite al usuario ingresar un número entero, y muestre
en pantalla el factorial de dicho número. NOTA: puede obviar la validación en
este ejercicio, pero recuerde que la función range no incluye al valor máximo
enviado como parámetro.
factorial de n = n! = 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * (n - 1) * n

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.